# Trouble referencing JSON imported object outside of FOR

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, properties, undefined

I have having trouble referencing my imported JSON data. If I run a FOR loop, then i==1 is found and the output works. If I try to reference it outside the FOR loop, then it fails with an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tname' of undefined"

This works...

```
for (var i in towns) {
    if (i == 1) {
        ctx.fillText(towns[i].Tname, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This next line fails with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tname' of undefined ". This extra line is written directly after the above loop.

```
ctx.fillText(towns[1].Tname, 0, 0);
```

I have tried many different formats but all fail. Output of "towns[1]" is "[Object Object]".

For those asking, here is snippet from towns.json:

```
{"towns":[
    {"Tid":"2057277", "Tname":"York"},
    {"Tid":"2057575", "Tname":"Yanchep"}
]}
```

This is JSON to towns[] code:

```
var towns[];
$.getJSON('towns.json', function(data) {
    for (var i in data.towns) { 
        towns[i] = data.towns[i] 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you please show how `towns` is defined?

Comment: Maybe your json contain "1" (character) but not 1  (integer). Try this : towns["1"]

Comment: @thefourtheye {"towns":[{"Tid":"2057277", "Tname":"York"},{"Tid":"2057575", "Tname":"Yanchep"}]}

Comment: $.getJSON('towns.json', function(data) {
  for (var i in data.towns) {
   towns[i] = data.towns[i]
  }
 });

Comment: @Taiki Tried towns["1"] but it gives the same error.

Comment: can you post your contents of `towns`.

Comment: @Mritunjay {"towns":[{"Tid":"2057277", "Tname":"York"},{"Tid":"2057575", "Tname":"Yanchep"}]}

Comment: @Taiki: Rubbish, they're exactly equivalent. All properties are strings.

Comment: @sacada: Did you put the `fillText` statement inside the `$.getJSON` callback as well, or did it went after it?

Comment: @Bergi: I have added the JSON callback to the question area above.

Comment: @sacada: getJson is Ajax call, so it's async. If you call the town right after the getJson block, the for block may not being executed and the towns variable is still empty. To fix it, simply put the code call the towns[1] in the Json callback function.

Bergi: Sorry, my bad. Just figured it out, thank you

Comment: @sacada: So does your overall code look [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your feedback. 
It was all a matter of syntax. Different for inside and outside the FOR loop.
@Bergi Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
//this worked inside the loop
ctx.fillText(towns[i].Tname, 0, 0);

//the same syntax failed outside the loop
ctx.fillText(towns[1].Tname, 0, 0);

//this syntax worked outside the loop
ctx.fillText(towns[1]['Tname'], 0, 0);
```

Comment: That's unlikely, your second and third syntax are completely equivalent. It might be a matter of positioning inside/outside of the callback; make sure you don't have a race condition.